# Picking right Locale on Android

Tags: java, android, localization

I'm trying to add support for different language in my app.

I figured out that the Hebrew language has two codes: 'he' and 'iw'. My device for example uses the 'iw' code but other devices might use the 'he' code.

If the user device language is Hebrew, then the app automatically picks the correct code, but I'd like to first open the app in English and then allow user to switch to Hebrew via a settings screen, so my question is:

How can I determine which code is going to work on the device?

Answer (score 0):

There is a method [`getAvailableLocales()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Locale.html#getAvailableLocales()) that gives a list of locale supported in the device. Probably you can get the list and verify which one will be available for you.

Comment: @jjang did this help you? Please let me know.